# Count how many employees with the same name exist in the database in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, count, window-functions

I have a data table of employees, I want to get how many same name employees in the database. Name information is saved as first_name and last_name. I have tried.

```
Select count(concat(first_name,'',last_name) as empname, (concat(first_name,'',last_name) as empname from xyz.
```

getting error.

Comment: **What** error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is missing some parentheses (brackets), and to use an aggregation function as well as a non-aggregated column, you must include the non-aggregated column in a `GROUP BY`

So your SQL should look like this:

```
Select count(concat(first_name,' ',last_name)) as countempname, 
(concat(first_name,' ',last_name)) as empname 
from xyz
GROUP BY (concat(first_name,' ',last_name));
```

Notice also that I added a space.  It is a bit odd to include an empty string in the concat.  Also as a short form, if you do not want to repeat the concat in the `GROUP BY`, you can replace it with the column ordinal number (in this case 2) so it becomes:

```
Select count(concat(first_name,' ',last_name)) as countempname, 
(concat(first_name,' ',last_name)) as empname 
from xyz    
GROUP BY 2;
```

Comment: @GMB Sorry my browser did something weird!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many times each first/last name tuple appears in the table, you can use aggregation:

```
select first_name, last_name, count(*) cnt
from xyz
group by first_name, last_name
```

This gives you one row per first/last name tuple, with the total count. Note that there is not point concatenating the variables; `group by` can operate of column tuples.

On the other hand, maybe you want the entire employee row, with an additional column that holds the total count of other rows having the same names. If so, you can use a window count instead of aggregation:

```
select x.*, count(*) over(partiton by first_name, last_name) cnt
from xyz
```